# CSS | Flexbox - my flexbox container is going on top of other container

Tags: html, css

I cant understand why my flexbox is going on top of my nav.
can someone please tell me?

```
https://codepen.io/doronhi/pen/RwpYyMw
```

thanks

Comment: Post the code in the question itself please

Comment: It's because **flex** class you got on very same div element.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of height property in your main-container class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your question and I got solution as well, by applying this css problem will not come again

```
.search-results-container {
    margin-top: 90%;
}
```

But I want to suggest you please add some code and screenshot in question, it will more clear to others and please follow some coding standard I faced difficulty to understand your code.